What happens if an exception leaves a destructor *not* during stack unwinding?
I'm experimenting with writing a Design-by-Contract library.  One of my types is defined as:
#include <stdexcept>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename Post>
class out {
  public:
    out(T& param, Post check = {})
      : param{param},
        copy{param}, //must be copyable; may throw
        check{std::move(check)}
    {}

    ~out() noexcept(false) {
        if (!check(param)) {
            param = std::move(copy); //rollback; assume this never throws
            if (!std::uncaught_exceptions()) //no exception currently being thrown
                throw std::invalid_argument("postcondition violated"); // leaves destructor if another exception is not being thrown
        }
    }

  private:
    T& param;
    T copy;
    Post check;
};

Here's an example of how it would be used:
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

struct is_not_empty {
    bool operator()(const std::vector<int>& v) { return !v.empty(); }

    /*not real code, just meant to illustrate the problem*/
    is_not_empty() { /*acquire some resource*/ }
    ~is_not_empty() { /*release some resource*/ }
    /******/
};

void function_with_postcondition(out<std::vector<int>, is_not_empty> v) {
} // Exception thrown here in out<>::~out

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v; //empty
    try {
        function_with_postcondition(v);
        assert(false); //not reached
    }
    catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {
    }
}

My question(s) - is the v object properly destructed in function_with_postcondition()?  Does the out<>::Post member get properly destructed?  Do I have a resource leak in this example? Am I recursively calling a destructor?  Is this well-defined?  What I'm really trying to get at is the (well-defined/undefined) order of operations of what exactly happens.
I know about stack unwinding, and I know throwing an exception while an exception is already being thrown results in a call to std::terminate() - that's what I'm trying to avoid with the call to std::uncaught_exceptions() in the destructor.  If the function throws an exception, I don't want to check the postcondition because the function exited abnormally.
Finally, why not do this another way (e.g. assert(), abort(), exit(), etc.)?  I'm attempting to write a library that checks function pre- and post-conditions that is robust in anomalous environments.  I'm trying to reduce the amount of boilerplate needed, while allowing for commit/rollback semantics that allow operations to be retried.

NEVER throw an exception in a destructor!

You probably want std::uncaught_exceptions as std::current_exception() return the one from within the catch block

@Jarod42 - Thanks, didn't realize that.  Updated the question, because that's not what I want to focus on.

https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4950/except.ctor#3.sentence-5

@StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ah, thank you!  My eyes probably glazed over that paragraph dozens of times.  Leave an answer, and I'll accept.

Please also take a look at this blog post by Andrzej Krzemieński about std::uncaught_exceptions, which goes into much more details about potential pitfalls of throwing in destructors.

@chris_se Thank you for sharing this.  I had to read through it a few times to "get" it, but this is definitely important to consider if you have a throwing destructor.

The quote [except.ctor]

3 If the destructor of an object is terminated by an exception, each destructor invocation that would be performed after executing the body of the destructor ([class.dtor]) and that has not yet begun execution is performed.

So we are guaranteed there is at least an attempt to call destructors of members and bases before unwinding the stack. This is all well and good so long as the other objects in question are reasonably well-behaved. If you compose your template with other types that let destructors throw, expect a swift call to std::terminate.
Also, be careful when plugging your types into standard library templates. Most (almost all) will have undefined behavior if a destructor from a supplied user type ever throws.

Thank you for the quick response!  I know that allowing an exception to leave a destructor is generally (almost always) bad practice, but I was trying to develop a non-intrusive way of plugging into existing code.  The real out is non-copyable and non-movable - hopefully that removes most of the footguns that come with improper use.

@jdc - That's excellent. I mostly left that note for posterity, since you already seem aware of the dangers in these waters.

For anyone that stumbles across this question, I wanted to provide the updated class definition that incorporates the additional words of wisdom from StoryTeller, Jarod42, and chris_se.
#include <stdexcept>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, typename Post>
class out {
  public:
    out(T& param, Post check = {})
      : param{param},
        copy{param}, //must be copyable; may throw
        check{std::move(check)},
        exception_count{std::uncaught_exceptions()}
    {}

    ~out() noexcept(false) {
        if (!check(param)) {
            param = std::move(copy); //rollback; assume this never throws
            if (exception_count == std::uncaught_exceptions())
                throw std::invalid_argument("postcondition violated"); // leaves destructor if another exception is not being thrown
        }
    }

    /*Make out non-copyable and non-movable.
      This makes this type less likely to be used by standard library templates.
    */
    out(const out&) = delete;
    out(out&&) = delete;
    out& operator=(const out&) = delete;
    out& operator=(out&&) = delete;
    /*****/

    T& get() noexcept { return param; }
    operator T&() noexcept { return get(); }

  private:
    T& param;
    T copy;
    Post check;
    int exception_count;
};

